# ¿Como puedo cargar una base de datos de archivo zip en python?

Tags: python, zip, dataset

dataset = pd.read_json('dataset_amazon(1).zip', lines= True)
dataset.head()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dataset_amazon(1).zip'

Answer (score 0):

podrias hacerlo asi si tuvieras una carpeta en tu disco C:\  en Windows:

```
dataset = pd.read_json(r'C:\datasets\dataset_amazon(1).zip', lines= True) dataset.head()
```

tambien podrias ponerlo junto a tu script de python asi:

```
    import os
    .
    .
    .
    
    CurrentDirectory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    DataSetPath = os.path.join(CurrentDirectory , './dataset_amazon(1).zip')
    dataset = pd.read_json(DataSetPath, lines= True, compression="zip") dataset.head()
```